# Utilities Hotline 93892851 is resumed currently

Tags: grammar

May I check if the sentence "Utilities Hotline 93892851 is resumed currently." is this correct grammatically? In particular, should the verb be "resume" or "resumed"?

Comment: What is "Utilities Hotline"?. For example, if an online resource, possibly "Utilities Hotline 93892851 is *back online*." If some other service, possibly "Utilities Hotline 93892851 is *now available*."

Comment: in this sentence "resumed" or resume ?

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically you are forming a sentence in the passive voice, so you use "is resumed" and not "is resume" since the passive voice is formed with the past participle of the verb.

I would not express this meaning with "is resumed". Consider "... is now operational." or "... is now back in service.". You can also use the past or perfect tense. "... has resumed." or "... resumed at 5 PM."

The passive voice "is resumed" is unusual in this context, as you wish to refer to a current state, rather than a (past) change of state.

Comment: Perhaps you should mention that resume relates to a change of state, and that's why you can't use it with **is**.

Comment: The trouble is that you can use resume in the passive voice. From example "muscles require therapy before running is resumed". I've tried to explain why it is unusual. If you can do better, then feel free to edit.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/resume), the word resume means **start again after a pause**. In the same way as start, resume defines an event- something that happens once only.

**[currently](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/currently)** is used when you want to talk about a state: a situation that has existed for a (possibly short) while and is expected to continue for a (possibly short) while. You might use it with a state word like busy, tired or working, but you cannot use it with an event word like resume.

If you want to emphasize that the service was not available and now it is, you can use **resume**, but you need to talk about it as an event in the past. If the service is available now, that means that it **resumed** at some time in the past. For a past event that is still having some effect, you use [present perfect](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/present-perfect-simple-and-present-perfect-continuous) **has resumed** rather than **is** and you leave out **currently**. In addition, I'm guessing that the hotline was still physically present even when it was not working, so you should clarify this by adding the word **service**.

> The Utilities Hotline 93892851 service has resumed.
>   Service on the Utilities Hotline 93892851 has resumed

If you want to describe the current state, you have to use a state adjective or verb, for example active, working, operational, available. My preferred word would be the [available](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/available):

> The Utilities Hotline 93892851 is currently available.